# CSS3 - box with notification bubble

Tags: html, css

How can i make box with image-less notification bubble like this one for example

[image: box with notification bubble]

as you can see this is box and image in center of it and image can be changed to another image on hover it, Also there is notification bubble (image-less) that might shows number of whatever.

How can i write it in html/css. ~ Thanks

Comment: The blue box with the numbers in it is obviously a `div` with a gradient background.  Google `gradient background css`.  It also has rounded corners.  Google `rounded corners css`.  The text and box also have a dropshadow.  Google `dropshadow css`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.outer{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: url(http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/prolific/prolific1206/prolific120600020/14161811-pencil--edit--icon.jpg);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.num_notifs {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%, #0052bf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#0052bf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#0052bf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="num_notifs">
        4329
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/4BmZm/1)