# CSS3 - top notification bubble

Tags: html, css

How to add pure css notification bubble for the following example

***Code CSS***

```
<style>

.outer{
width:103px;
height:113px;
display:inline-block;
padding:5px;
margin:25px 14px 15px 14px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#8E9FA9;
text-transform: uppercase;
border:1px solid #cccece;
text-align:center;
background-color:#f8f8f8;
letter-spacing: -0.06em;
-webkit-text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px;
moz-text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px;
text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);

}

.outer:hover {
color:#7D878E !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 }

a.outer span {
font-size: 14px;
display:block;
padding:86px 0 6px 0;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#f1f2f3;
background-position:50% 18px;
}

a.outer span:hover {background-position:50% -98px;}

a.outer.add_user span {background-image:url(icon_big_user_add.png);}

</style>
```

***Code HTML***

```
<a href="#" class="outer add_user">

<span>Test</span>

</a>
```

***Results***

[image]

***Question***

How to add pure css notification bubble at the top of the box just like this example.

[image]

as you might seen there is blue ball that shows numbers, how to apply such notification ball based on the above example. ~ Thanks

Comment: Down vote ! for what .. am i said something wrong !! i'm seeking for help give me help rather than down vote :(

Comment: Because SO is a place for asking specific questions, not to have someone write your code for you. You have shown no effort in trying to attempt this yourself. That's why you have received downvotes.

Comment: You asked it before as well! see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199133/css3-box-with-notification-bubble/17199553#17199553 <-- its from you!!!! but why?

Comment: @BenM thanks for telling me this.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui i did tried your example but didn't fit will so i made littel modification and i wasn't able to apply class "num_notifs".

Comment: but why? tell me the problem indeed tell us the problem.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui if you tried your class "num_notifs" upon the above example, it will be completely malformed so i can not apply if you can, that would be very nice of you Mohammad. ~ thanks

Comment: but what type of output do you want?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui see this box http://i.stack.imgur.com/DpkjJ.png i've wrote its code in the above example, i just need notification bubble on top left corner of it .. not important to be exact like this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/SVz16.png but anything even the idea only ~ thanks a lot that would helps me a lot

Comment: @JackBen check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/ze5B5/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui masha' allah, that is perfect just like i need , thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @JackBen alhamdulillah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/ze5B5/).

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    width:103px;
    height:113px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:25px 14px 15px 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#8E9FA9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border:1px solid #cccece;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    letter-spacing: -0.06em;
    -webkit-text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px;
    moz-text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px;
    text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
.outer:hover {
    color:#7D878E !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
a.outer span {
    font-size: 14px;
    display:block;
    padding:80px 0 6px 0;
}

.num_notifs {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%, #0052bf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#0052bf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00b7ea 0%,#0052bf 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#0052bf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="outer add_user">

    <div class="num_notifs">4319</div>
<span>Test</span>

</a>
```